# Progress bar HUD for react native

Tags: react-native, progress-bar

I have been looking for react native modules in which indeterminate progress bars are implemented. I need it for when I show it as feedback when a user logs on to my application and the promise arrives. I have tried some but I would like to get one with a good design

for example https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-progress-hud
this is not maintainable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need ActivityIndicator?
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator.html

Also there are many community libraries.
https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-indicators

Comment: thanks for you recomendations, i try integrated this modules

Comment: thanks for you answer, i  decided implement this module https://github.com/joinspontaneous/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay, i seems that is a good option for feedback action of user

Comment: Update: this module have some bugs, i decide not use this module